# Sending special characters in HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, enctype

I have an input field (which is filled automatically) with the format name `<myemail@host.com>`. I gave the form `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, but when I retrieve it in PHP, it shows only the name. Please help me retrieving the email too.

My HTML form:

```
<form action="{$path_site}{$index_file}" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Your Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sender_name" size="37" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>To</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="reciever_name" size="37" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value)" onblur="fill()" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And PHP code:

```
echo $msg_sender_name = $info[reciever_name];
```

Comment: Could you show the code you use?

Comment: could you add your form's HTML ?

Comment: Can you please show me the code so I can have a look at it and see what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Which input field isn't working? What does the PHP code look like?

Comment: I have posted the HTML form .

Comment: What do `lookup()` and `fill()` do? How is `$info` set?

Comment: $info = $_REQUEST . lookup() and fill() are javascript functions to retrieve the list of users

Comment: Are you sure that the input field really has some value? Your question title mentions "special characters", but you haven't show any special character in your code. Please, give us some more information.

Comment: I dont know whether <> are special charecters or not, but I am not able to retrieve them on my PHP side . if the text is like myName<myEmail@email.com> ,ifno['reciever_name'] displays only myName !

Comment: Have you properly **escaped** the value? If you display it as HTML, then everything in `<` and `>` is considered a tag (unknown one) and not visible. You should place that information in the question (edit it).

Comment: Aaaah! I should have thought that you may have placed the information in the question, but you had the problem with formatting the question properly. By the way - __your question suffered the same problem as your program__. ;-) Good work, asbjornu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracting the information from comments, where you say:

> if the text is like "myName<myEmail@email.com>", `info['reciever_name']` displays only "myName"

I would say that your problem is related to the *displaying the results*, and is not related to the form.

You probably display the received string as HTML, where the characters "<" and ">" **are special**.

Instead of

```
echo $info['reciever_name'];
```

you should use the [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($info['reciever_name'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

This is the most common bug in PHP *(and in many other languages)*.

You should escape **all the text you are displaying**, especially when it comes from *untrusted* sources - and every value provided by the user *is untrusted*.

Failing to escape the output you risk the security of your users - you may want to read about [Cross-site-scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

The following PHP code

```
echo $msg_sender_name = $info[reciever_name];
```

seems to be missing a couple of quotes. Try this instead:

```
echo $msg_sender_name = $info['reciever_name'];
```

Comment: It should work even without quotes, unless there happens to be a constant called `reciever_name`.

Comment: @Juhana: yes, but that is a very bad programming practice. _(I know you know this, but some future reader may need that notice)_. I also recall that this _feature_ was planned to be removed in some future version of the language.